# Python 3.3 library abpy, file undefined

Tags: python, filter, fetch, ads, python-3.3

I'm using a library ABPY (library [here](https://github.com/atereshkin/abpy)) for python but it is in older version i think. I'm using Python 3.3. 
I did fix some PRINT errors, but that's how much i know, I'm really new on programing.

I want to fetch some webpage and filter it from advertising and then print it again.

EDITED after Sg'te'gmuj told me how to convert from python 2.x to 3.x this is my new code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.1

import cgitb;cgitb.enable()

import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.build_opener()
response.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.youtube.com")

html = response.read()

from abpy import Filter
with open("easylist.txt") as f:
ABPFilter = Filter(file('easylist.txt'))
ABPFilter.match(html)


print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print (html)
```

Now it is displaying a blank page

Answer (score 2):

Just took a peek at the library, it seems that the file "easylist.txt" does not exist; you need to create the file, and populate it with the appropriate filters (in whatever format ABP specifies).

Additionally, it appears it takes a file object; try something like this instead:

```
with open("easylist.txt") as f:
    ABPFilter = Filter(f)
```

I can't say this is wholly accurate though since I have no experience with the library, but looking at it's code I'd suspect either of the two are the problem, if not both.

**Addendum #1**

Looking at the code more in-depth, I have to agree that even if that fix I supplied does work, you're going to have more problems (it's in 2.x as you suggested, when you're using 3.x). I'd suggest utilizing Python's 2to3 function, to convert from typical Python 2 to Python 3 code (it's not foolproof though). The command line would be as so:

```
2to3 -w abpy.py
```

That will convert it from Python 2.x to 3.x code, and re-write the source file.

**Addendum #2**

The code to pass the file object should be the "f" variable, as shown above (modified to represent that; I wasn't paying attention and just left the old file function call in the argument).

You need to pass a URI to the function as well:

```
ABPFilter.match(URI)
```

You'll need to modify the code to pass those items into an array (I'm assuming at least); I'm playing with it now to see. At present I'm getting a rule error (not a Python error; but merely error handling used by abpy.py, which is good because it suggests that it's the right train of thought).

The code for the Filter.match function is as following (after using the 2to3 Python script):

```
def match(self, url, elementtype=None):
    tokens = RE_TOK.split(url)
    print(tokens)
    for tok in tokens:
        if len(tok) > 2:
            if tok in self.index:
                for rule in self.index[tok]:
                    if rule.match(url, elementtype=elementtype):
                        print(str(rule))
```

What this means is you're, at present, at a point where you need to program the functionality; it appears this module only indicates the rule. However, that is still useful.

What this means is that you're going to have to modify this function to take the HTML, in place of the the "url" parameter. You're going to regex the HTML (this may be rather intensive) for a list of URIs and then run each item through the match loop Where you go from there to actually filter the nodes, I'm not sure; but there is a list of filter types, so I'm assuming there is a typical procedural ABP does to remove the nodes (possibly, in some cases merely by removing the given URI from the HTML?)

> References
>
> http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/2to3.html

Comment: At firs thank you alot.
The error is gone but now it is not displaying nothing.
I did create that file I took it from https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt

I have no idea how to finisht this code i'm posting my new code on a answer below pls take a look at it.

Comment: No problem. Hmm, can you explain what you mean that it displays nothing? (Meaning Python is not passing anything to the console?) I'm taking another look; it seems like it takes a URI in the match, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for telling me how to convert but it displays nothing. I'm reediting my post and putting my new code in there have a look at it pls.

Comment: It is blank, Nothing apears on http request

Comment: Sorry for the delay; as far as I can gather by looking at the code, this module doesn't actually remove the node but merely matches a given URI against what rules it has, and tells you whether this is an ad or not (based on the rules). It does dictate rule "type"; which gives reason for me to suspect that you could build off of this to remove a given ad based on the type it detects for a given URI (with understanding you'll need to parse the page for those URIs and pass each URI through the match loop).

Comment: O really :/ do you know any other solution to this ? any library ?

Comment: What do you think about http://www.uzbl.org/wiki/adblock And dont worry for your delay :).. I really appreciate what you are doing here :)

Comment: I think that'd certainly be the place to start, the adblock.js (mentioned in the page you linked; http://www.uzbl.org/wiki/adblock.js) itself seems like a good idea (would require a chain of calls though I think). You'd need to pass the actual filter list to that JS array, so it has a full list of items it needs to filter, but that file looks like it actually removes the nodes. But I can't say for sure without having experience with the given suggestions.

Comment: Can I contact you Sg'te'gmuj privatly !? any contact of you ?

Comment: Sorry but no, there is a reason why my name is Ghost :P (I'm a pretty private person). That said, if they're any other questions you have just ask here (I get a notification when you comment).